# Is the flashing black caused by CSS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

The home page of this site has a LayerSlider with a weird side effect: http://ironhaus.com/ As each slide loads, the white space at the end of a line flashes black. The class is ls-l, which doesn't seem to have a style in the stylesheet. I've never seen this behavior before without being triggered by some kind of user action. Well, I haven't seen it since the old  tag was put out of its misery.

This is a WordPress site with the LayerSlider plugin having the problem, but I'm guessing the problem could show up in other structures as well.

Comment: Does the  whitespace popup or it's jumping?

Comment: After the page loads fully, each of the overlay layers flashes black highlight just once in the white space that is part of the <p>. Double checking, the behavior shows in Mozilla Firefox, but not in IE. I have screenshots if there were any way to attach them here.

Comment: You can attach whatever a pastebin or some another storage and create jsfiddle.net